# USB stick not detected

Tags: usb

USB stick is not working any more. If I look for it in the Disks app, I am able to see this:

[image]
and the Gparted, as you can see i am only able to see my SSD: [[image]]
I tried to unplug it, and plug it again after few minutes. I tried to use it on another computer. I"m not able to see it on Gparted app.
That is the output for sudo lsblk -f and sudo lsblk -m:

[image]

Comment: Did you try unplugging it and plugging it in again after waiting several seconds? Looks like it has been ejected.

Comment: Please edit your post to add the output of the following terminal window commands: `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m`

Comment: If the Disks app can _see_ the storage device, but gparted cannot, that doesn't make sense. GPartEd should be able to see and tell you more about it than the Disks app. Could you try running Disks again, but this time, check if the storage device is there?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like either the storage device is

1. Unformatted
2. Not properly formatted
3. Corrupted
4. Not formatted in a file system recongizable by Ubuntu.

For Option 4 I cannot exactly give you an example of which filesystems Ubuntu or the computer wouldn't recognize. But, that's still a possibility.

However, Options 2 and 3 I can relate to. I was just having a similar issue with an SD card reader. I needed to reformat it because a Windows computer was saying it was corrupt. Gparted could *see* the SD card, but PCManFM or Nautilus (file explorers) could not detect it or even read the contents. I ended up reformatting it just fine.

Because your PC can see the storage device, you should be able to run Gparted and reformat it. If you have files you need to get off of it, keep trying to read the contents using a file explorer, or, if you have access to one, try using a different computer, even a Windows PC if you must.

If no other system can read the contents, it is likely the storage device fits within Options 2 and 3.

Could you comment here with your results if you tried this?

**Edit:** In my SD card situation, my PC (or any other PC for that matter) could not do so much as tell me its storage space limits or how much space is taken up.